# SherlockFragmentActivity not restoring fragments correctly when working with ViewPager

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock, android-viewpager, fragment

I was using ActionBarSherlock and ViewPager to have 4 fragments as the tab pages in a SherlockFragmentActivity.

In normal conditions, this solution worked fine.

However, if the application exited abnormally, i.e., killed by the Android OS because of memory shortage, the ViewPager was unable to attach the newly created fragments to the activity any more when navigating back to the SherlockFragmentActivity.

With lots of debugging, I finally found out that SherlockFragmentActivity 'remembered' the fragments attached to it. When it was re-created, it would re-create and attach the fragments to itself, that prevented ViewPager from attaching any new fragment to the activity.

I worked around this issue by overwrite SherlockFragmentActivity#onSaveInstanceState with an empty implementation to force SherlockFragmentActivity to forget all the fragments. But I still have not any perfect solution.

I suspected this is a defect of SherlockFragmentActivity.

As a summary, I think SherlockFragmentActivity has a defect of restoring inner fragments when working with ViewPager.

Did anybody encounter the same issue?

Comment: If you're assuming a bug, then you should be able to post a sample replicating the behavior.

Comment: What version of ABS are you using?

Comment: which kind of view pager adapter are you extends from?

Comment: I was using ActionbarSherlock 4.3. My ViewPager was android.support.v4.view.ViewPager. My pager adapter extended from android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter. I will prepare a sample to double confirm it before reporting to the author of ActionBarSherlock.

Answer (score 0):

Based on what you have said, I see little evidence of a bug here. Your solution is a good one which is widely used.

However I do want to question your analysis. If the fragments are static (XML) then Android will recreate them automatically. However, if you are creating the fragments dynamically ( and I assume you are if you are using tabs) then the Android system will not recreate them automatically after the activity is destroyed. In this case you should use onSaveInstanceState to programmatically restore the fragment/tab.

Although you have not mentioned the issue of configuration changes , if you are using ABS, you should not attempt to handle the configuration change in your app. This is the only deviation from "standard" that I have encountered whilst using ABS.

If you are looking for high quality responses here then I suggest that you post code and a logcat trace.

Comment: I will prepare a sample to double confirm it before reporting to the author of ActionBarSherlock

Answer (score 0):

I've encountered similar issue. Solution works for me:

1. At first, fragments are being re-created using default constructor. So if You passing some args in your custom constructor to fragments, You should save 'em duriong onSaveInstanceState and getting 'em out in onCreateView().

   It will save your fragments if whole app is not killed by OS.
2. To restore fragments after whole app re-create, use SharedPrefs to save important data. 
   Good place to do it in onStop() method and restore in onCreateView().

If You need code sample let me know, but it seems it would not be a problem for You.

Comment: thanks, I will prepare a sample to double confirm it before reporting to the author of ActionBarSherlock. I will invite you to inspect my code.